# Shortening Angular display variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap's breadcrumb in conjunction with Angular to output the variables, as:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li ng-repeat="breadcrumb in box.breadcrumbs"><a href="#">{{ breadcrumb.folder }}</a></li>
</ol>
```

Let's say I have an output of:

`a / b / c / d / e / f / g`

but this ends up stretching past the width of my page. Is there an easy way (or in-built) to set the output to:

`a / b / ... / f / g`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a built-in way, but it's easy to write a custom filter that does what you want, and you can reuse it everywhere

something like this:

```
angular.module('myFilters', []).filter('breadcrumbs', function() {
  return function(breadcrumbsArray) {
    if (breadcrumbsArray.length > 5) {
      // return a new array with your desired structure
      return [].concat(
        breadcrumbsArray.slice(0, 2), // first two elements
        {
          // this would be the '...' element, so you have to put the other info you need
          folder: '...'
        },
        breadcrumbsArray.slice(-2) // last two elements
      );
    }
    return breadcrumbsArray;
  };
});
```

and use it like:

```
<li ng-repeat="breadcrumb in box.breadcrumbs | breadcrumbs">
```

I don't know what you intend to do if the user clicks that '...', but if you want to deactivate the filter you could just pass a boolean to the filter function

**edit**
you can see it working [here](https://jsbin.com/fixupa/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: I tried your code but nothing was displayed. I'm not sure I'm putting the code in the right place.

Comment: where are you putting it? maybe you forgot to add it to the module dependecies or just add it to the same module, I added a jsbin to the answer so you can see it working

Comment: This might sound a little forward, but, will you have my children?

Answer (score 0):

If it were just `a / b / c / d / e ...`, you could use [text-overflow: ellipsis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) (don't forget overflow: hidden with that).

Otherwise, I would split the array in half over two `div`s, with another `div` with `...` in between.

Or I would split the array in half and limit the number of breadcrumbs in each to a maximum. This would however not be adjusted to a screen size.